# BitTorrent: Download not starting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, bittorrent

I am trying to implement a [bittorrent tracker in Laravel](https://github.com/Comforse/laratracker). However, I am stuck at the moment as the download won't start. There is one peer which it appears to be seeding and I am 100% sure that it is connectable. But, when I run a second client on a different machine, the download won't start. It is stuck at "Connecting to peers" (uTorrent).

From the tracker I am sending the following response when the client makes an announce:

```
d8:intervali1000e12:min intervali300e5:peers18:�ؤ�i�ؑ�XÚJU�6e
```

In the downloading client I have the following data:

[image]
[image]

Here's my announce code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Announce;

use App\Helpers\BencodeHelper;
use App\Models\Peer;
use App\Models\PeerTorrent;
use App\Models\Torrent;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class AnnounceController extends Controller
{
    const __INTERVAL = 1000;
    const __TIMEOUT = 120;
    const __INTERVAL_MIN = 60;
    const __MAX_PPR = 20;

    public function announce(Request $request)
    {
        Log::info($request->fullUrl());
        $status = 200;
        $content = "";
        $passkey = Input::get('passkey');
        $peer_id = Input::get('peer_id');
        $port = Input::get('port');
        $info_hash = Input::get('info_hash');
        $downloaded = Input::get('uploaded') ? intval(Input::get('uploaded')) : 0;
        $uploaded = Input::get('uploaded') ? intval(Input::get('uploaded')) : 0;
        $left = Input::get('left') ? intval(Input::get('left')) : 0;
        $compact = Input::get('compact') ? intval(Input::get('compact')) : 0;
        $no_peer_id = Input::get('no_peer_id') ? intval(Input::get('no_peer_id')) : 0;

        $ipAddress = '';
        // Check for X-Forwarded-For headers and use those if found
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && ('' !== trim($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))) {
            $ipAddress = (trim($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']));
        } else {
            if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && ('' !== trim($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))) {
                $ipAddress = (trim($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
            }
        }

        $port = $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];
        /*if(!$port || !ctype_digit($port) || intval($port) < 1 || intval($port) > 65535)
        {
            $content = BencodeHelper::track("Invalid client port.");
            $status = 401;
            return (new Response(AnnounceController::track($content), $status))
                ->header('Content-Type', $value);
        }

        if ($port == 999 && substr($peer_id, 0, 10) == '-TO0001-XX') {
            die("d8:completei0e10:incompletei0e8:intervali600e12:min intervali60e5:peersld2:ip12:72.14.194.184:port3:999ed2:ip11:72.14.194.14:port3:999ed2:ip12:72.14.194.654:port3:999eee");
        }*/


        if (!$passkey) {
            $content = BencodeHelper::track("Missing passkey.");
            $status = 401;
            return (new Response(AnnounceController::track($content), $status))
                ->header('Content-Type', $value);
        }


        $torrent = Torrent::getByInfoHash(sha1($info_hash));
        if (!$torrent || $torrent == null) {
            $content = "Torrent not registered with this tracker.";
            $status = 404;
            return (new Response(AnnounceController::track($content), $status))
                ->header('Content-Type', $value);
        }

        $user = User::has('passkeys', '=', $passkey)->get();

        if ($user == null) {
            $content = BencodeHelper::track("Invalid passkey.");
            $status = 401;
            return (new Response(AnnounceController::track($content), $status))
                ->header('Content-Type', $value);
        }

        $peer = Peer::getByHashAndPasskey(bin2hex($peer_id), $passkey);

        if ($peer == null) {
            $peer = Peer::create([
                'hash' => bin2hex($peer_id),
                'user_agent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
                'ip_address' => $ipAddress,
                'passkey' => $passkey,
                'port' => $port
            ]);
        }

        if (!$info_hash || strlen($info_hash) != 20) {
            $content = BencodeHelper::track("Invalid info_hash.");
            $status = 401;
            return (new Response(AnnounceController::track($content), $status))
                ->header('Content-Type', $value);
        }


        $peer_torrent = PeerTorrent::getByPeerAndTorrent($peer, $torrent);

        if ($peer_torrent == null) {
            $peer_torrent = PeerTorrent::create([
                'peer_id' => $peer->id,
                'torrent_id' => $torrent->id,
                'uploaded' => $uploaded,
                'downloaded' => $downloaded,
                'left' => $left,
                'stopped' => false
            ]);

        } else {
            $peer_torrent->uploaded = $uploaded;
            $peer_torrent->downloaded = $downloaded;
            $peer_torrent->left = $left;
            $peer_torrent->save();
        }

        $seeders = $torrent->getSeedersCount();
        $leechers = $torrent->getLeechersCount();
        $resp = "";
        if ($compact != 1) {
            $resp = "d" . $this->benc_str("interval") . "i" . AnnounceController::__INTERVAL . "e" . $this->benc_str("peers") . "l";
        } else {
            $resp = "d" . $this->benc_str("interval") . "i" . AnnounceController::__INTERVAL . "e" . $this->benc_str("min interval") . "i" . 300 . "e5:" . "peers";
        }

        $peer = array();

        $peer_num = 0;
        foreach ($torrent->getPeersArray() as $row) {
            if ($compact != 1) {
                if ($row["peer_id"] === $peer->hash) {
                    continue;
                }

                $resp .= "d" . $this->benc_str("ip") . $this->benc_str($row['ip']);

                if ($no_peer_id == 0) {
                    $resp .= $this->benc_str("peer id") . $this->benc_str($row["peer_id"]);
                }

                $resp .= $this->benc_str("port") . "i" . $row["port"] . "e" . "e";

            } else {
                $peer_ip = explode('.', $row["ip"]);
                $peer_ip = pack("C*", $peer_ip[0], $peer_ip[1], $peer_ip[2], $peer_ip[3]);
                $peer_port = pack("n*", (int)$row["port"]);
                $time = intval((time() % 7680) / 60);

                if ($left == 0) {
                    $time += 128;
                }

                $time = pack("C", $time);
                $peer[] = $time . $peer_ip . $peer_port;
                $peer_num++;
            }
        }

        if ($compact != 1) {
            $resp .= "ee";
        } else {
            $o = "";
            for ($i = 0; $i < $peer_num; $i++) {
                $o .= substr($peer[$i], 1, 6);
            }
            $resp .= strlen($o) . ':' . $o . 'e';
        }

        $this->benc_resp_raw($resp);
    }

    public function benc_resp($d)
    {
        return $this->benc_resp_raw($this->benc(array('type' => 'dictionary', 'value' => $d)));
    }

    public function benc_resp_raw($x)
    {
        header("Content-Type: text/plain");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");

        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'] == 'gzip') {
            header("Content-Encoding: gzip");
            echo gzencode($x, 9, FORCE_GZIP);
        } else {
            echo $x;
        }
    }

    function benc($obj)
    {
        if (!is_array($obj) || !isset($obj["type"]) || !isset($obj["value"]))
            return;
        $c = $obj["value"];
        switch ($obj["type"]) {
            case "string":
                return $this->benc_str($c);
            case "integer":
                return $this->benc_int($c);
            case "list":
                return $this->benc_list($c);
            case "dictionary":
                return $this->benc_dict($c);
            default:
                return;
        }
    }

    public function benc_str($s)
    {
        return strlen($s) . ":$s";
    }

    public function benc_int($i)
    {
        return "i" . $i . "e";
    }

    public function benc_list($a)
    {
        $s = "l";
        foreach ($a as $e) {
            $s .= $this->benc($e);
        }
        $s .= "e";
        return $s;
    }

    public function benc_dict($d)
    {
        $s = "d";
        $keys = array_keys($d);
        sort($keys);
        foreach ($keys as $k) {
            $v = $d[$k];
            $s .= $this->benc_str($k);
            $s .= $this->benc($v);
        }
        $s .= "e";
        return $s;
    }


    public function hex2bin($hex)
    {
        $r = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hex); $i += 2) {
            $r .= chr(hexdec($hex{$i} . $hex{($i + 1)}));
        }
        return $r;
    }
}
```

I am not quite sure what am I missing here.

Comment: If your client is getting seeds (apparently 5) from the tracker, and the addresses look correct, the tracker may be working fine. Are the machines behind the same public IP, behind a NAT? I'd suspect a client issue like that instead.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: They are not. The "Seeding" machine is from a seedbox and it is definitely publicly accesible. The leeching machines are on different hosts in different locations and IPs.

Comment: Seems like the response to the announce has some encoding problems? The � symbols are very unlikely to be expected there.

Comment: @Oldskool: i think that the character should be there (due to encoding) since that part of text comes from the ''pack()'' function because it is supposed to be a "compact" list of peers

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: You seem to be missing some database stuffs

Comment: That class has changes since the original post. You can follow the code on github: https://github.com/Comforse/laratracker/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Announce/AnnounceController.php

Comment: That's what I'm looking at. Tried cloning it, lots of stuff missing to run it.

Comment: right, the repo is missing the config/database.php file

Comment: Unless there is something profoundly abnormal it it thats not the issue im having. Copied one over, migrations amd seeds are empty.

Comment: Throw errors actually

Comment: I did not write any migrations yet. I am planning to, but there is none yet. There is a basic schema file here: https://github.com/Comforse/laratracker/blob/master/storage/sql/schema.sql

Comment: Download? That happens on the Client Side.

Comment: the problem work around the encoding try check your php file encoding.

Comment: [here is a single tracker implementation](https://github.com/IevaZarina/Tracker)

Comment: Did you tried to run this from other locations, say a different ISP? or using a VPN from another country? It appears that some ISPs tend to block any torrent activities within their customers - happened to me a lot.

Comment: I think the problem is that the tracker instead of register the port that the connecting peer sends in the announce string, the tracker register the remote port that the peer is connecting from. That is almost certainly the wrong port to use.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's because you constantly set

```
->header('Content-Type', $value);
```

without ever setting `$value`? So the "Announce-Response" is malformed?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    $port = $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];
> ```

I think the problem is that the tracker instead of register the port that the connecting peer sends in the announce string, the tracker register the remote port that the peer is connecting from.
That is almost certainly the wrong port to use.